# Mockito: How to call custom method after real method call?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a **emailService** @Spy object which has send function. I would like to do something like this.

```
when(emailClientService.send(any())).thenCallRealMethod().thenCallMyCustomMethod(...)
```

Comment: "thenCallRealMethod" has to return a class or interface class which implements "thenCallMyCustomMethod"

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama I think it would be wise if he add callMyCustomMethod in the actual code.

Comment: On my test I would like to call some function after real function call and don't want to change source code implementation.

Comment: @GevorgHarutyunyan In your test cases why don't you do something `when(emailClientService.send(any())).thenCallRealMethod()` then call your `callMyCustomMethod()`

Comment: In my tests I don't know when it will be called, but after call I should do some work.

Comment: Wrap the two methods in a function/method which calls them in the order you want them called.  Then have the trigger call the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
   Mockito.doAnswer((Answer<Object>) invocation -> {
        invocation.callRealMethod(); // calling emailService.send()
        callMyCustomMethod();
        ...
        return null;
    }).when(emailService).send(any());
```